# does github change capitalization?

Tags: android-studio, github

So, I just uploaded a couple files to github. Before I uploaded them I saved a copy of the folder on my local desktop.

I changed a class name from `SignupRequest.java` to `SignUpRequest.java`. I changed both the file name and it's usage in the file.

I upload it and then pull from the same place. And only the usage was capitalized `SignUpRequest`, not the file name `SignupRequest.java`.

I checked the copy I made before hand and sure enough, both were capitalized.`SignUpRequest.java`&`SignUpRequest`

Github also had it as `SignupRequest.java` & `SignUpRequest`

Does anybody know anything about this?

Comment: Did you do a `git mv` to rename the file? This sounds like user error, not `git`/GitHub error.

Comment: What os are you on ?

Comment: @SitiSchu macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz I did not, with every file name change I need to do git mv?

Comment: If you're trying to change the name of the file in a `git` repository (which is, ultimately, what GitHub _is_), then yes.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz ah okay, I just changed the file in android studio using refactor

Comment: You probably need to remove the all version of the file. git rm `SignupRequest.java` . Then, the steps are: `git rm SignupRequest.java`   `git status` (will show you each modified file) and then commit and push. Hope this help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On case insensitive, case preserving filesystems, git (like most systems) will maintain the original case unless you explicitly perform a "case changing rename".  This is useful and prevents you from accidentally changing the case of a file when a tool behaves poorly, assuming case insensitivity, and rewrites the filename.

To change the case of a file, use `git mv`, and git should show you that the file is renamed:

```
% git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        renamed:    foo.c -> FOO.c
```